# "undefined reference to" error. (from a member function to static member variable)

Tags: c++, g++

I got a following error upon linking.

A member variable ClassBB::THR can't be accessed from a function ClassBB::bound().

What's strange is, from ClassBB::setThreshold(T v) function, which seems in the same condition with ClassBB::bound() in that both are template member function, ClassBB::THR is successfully accessed (I'm only talking about compile time, of course).

I'm still new to C++ especially in template architecture. Thanks!

Environment: Ubuntu 10.10, G++ 4.4.5 via Eclipse Indigo CDT

Error msg (only linker's part):

```
Building target: SampleEclipsePrj
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -o "SampleEclipsePrj"  ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/IntersectAngle.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/ReadRealTime.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/SampleEclipsePrj.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/SampleEclipsePrjThread.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/Slope.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/Transform.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/Utility.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/main3_linux.o ./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/reader.o   -lcv -lcxcore -lhighgui
./src/SampleEclipsePrjFinal/SampleEclipsePrj.o: In function `ClassBB<double>::bound()':
/home/user/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SampleEclipsePrj/Includes/ClassBB.hpp:203: undefined reference to `ClassBB<double>::THR'
/home/user/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SampleEclipsePrj/Includes/ClassBB.hpp:204: undefined reference to `ClassBB<double>::THR'
/home/user/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SampleEclipsePrj/Includes/ClassBB.hpp:206: undefined reference to `ClassBB<double>::THR'
/home/user/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SampleEclipsePrj/Includes/ClassBB.hpp:207: undefined reference to `ClassBB<double>::THR'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SampleEclipsePrj] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Note: Got the same result both on Eclipse and terminal.

Code-B (snipped to show related part only):

```
#ifndef _BBOUND_H
#define _BBOUND_H

template<class T>
class ClassBB
{
        T *pMap;
        float u1, v1, u2, v2;
        int w, h;

        float converge(float sp, float ep, float steps, float fixedPt,
                float thr);
        static T THR;

    public:
        ClassBB() :
                pMap(NULL), u1(0), v1(0), u2(0), v2(0), w(0), h(0)
        {
        }
        ClassBB(float U1, float V1, float U2, float V2);
        static void setThreshold(T v);
    int bound();
        ~ClassBB();
};

template<class T>
ClassBB<T>::ClassBB(float U1, float V1, float U2, float V2)
{// do something
}

template<class T>
void ClassBB<T>::setThreshold(T v)
{
    ClassBB::THR = v;
}

//Converge
template<class T>
float ClassBB<T>::converge(float sp, float ep, float step, float fixedPt,
        float thr)
{// do something
    return point;
}
//The bound algorithm
template<class T>
int ClassBB<T>::bound()
{
    u2 = converge(0.75, 0.5, 0.03125, v2, ClassBB::THR);
    v2 = converge(0.25, 0.0, 0.03125, u2, THR); // Both don't work.
    return 1;
}

template<class T>
ClassBB<T>::~ClassBB()
{// do something
}

#endif
```

Code-C (instantiate the class):

```
#ifndef _SCENE_CLASSIFIER_H
#define _SCENE_CLASSIFIER_H
#include "ClassBB.hpp"

class ClassCC
{
        ClassBB<double> bb; //Branch and Bound

    public:
        ClassCC(int W = 0, int H = 0); 
        ~ClassCC(); 
};
#endif
```

Comment: Where is the code which instantiates `ClassBB<double>`?

Comment: Sorry now it's added as Code-C where ClassBB<double> is instantiated.

Comment: I have edited the question title, as that error cannot happen with a non-static member variable.

Comment: @dribeas, thanks. That's helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create the storage for the static variable. Just add:

```
template<class T> T ClassBB<T>::THR;
```

Note that for normal member variables, the storage is generated whenever a new instance of the template class is created. But for static members, a "static" place should be defined for them, hence the explicit definition.

Comment: Question. Suppose this template was used for the same class in two different source files. Then the static variable would be defined in two different source files. Wouldn't that then cause an error during the link phase? Something like the variable is defined twice? (I cannot remember the exact message, only that I seem to recall this sort of problem).

Comment: @John: No, the compiler emits special *weak* symbols for those templated static variables that are merged together when linking.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, now I know how to do statics for templates!

Answer (score 4):

You need to define static variables.

```
template<class T>
class ClassBB {
    // ...
    static T THR;
    // ...
};

template<class T>
T ClassBB<T>::THR;
```